# Are there algorithms or some programming styles that fits a CISC or RISC better?

Tags: algorithm, x86, arm, mips, processor

Seems both are used for various reasons, ARM for power consumption, x86 for its extended features.

I'm still curious, since my computer science culture is a little empty, what was the true purpose of CISC chips like x86 (or their predecessors).

Would our computer be better if they had RISC instead (for example if microsoft ported its kernel and toolchain for RISC like MIPS or ARM) ? Or would it be impossible as a task to accomplish ?

I'm reading the purpose of CISC was the ability to getting closer to higher level languages, which I find odd. Was there a deal between intel and microsoft to focus on x86 instead ?

Comment: Odd or not, variable-length instructions with complex functionality reduce code size, which used to be very important decades ago and (un?)surprisingly still is. ARM and MIPS have now got 16-bit instruction sets, although they started out with 32-bit instructions. And that's to reduce memory waste.

Comment: IMHO, the biggest advantage of RISC machines is the larger amount of (non-dedicated) registers, for which compilers can generate better instruction sequences without having to spill registers to temp storage. Orthogonality of the instruction set helps, too.

Comment: Your computer's x86 or x86_64 is most probably really a RISC at the core, it translates the CISC instructions into sequences of (internal) RISC-type operations, that are then scheduled for execution. And said CPU also has much more internal registers than what the programmer sees. The visible architecture is CISC, for compatibility reasons and (much more importantly) for code compactness (on today's machines, an access to RAM takes time enough for a few hundred instructions).

Comment: Info in last parenthesis is related to frequency, not really architecture.

Answer (score 7):

blah blah blah blah blah rant blah blah blah blah

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was worth reading. I admit I love to know the hows, I like to understand the design of things, and I admit I'll never trully understand business.

Comment: dwelch, do you happen to have some resources to further your answer?  I'm very interested in the future of ARM vs Intel (as are a lot of others I'm sure)